# Mysql and PHP select and display columns

Tags: php, mysql, rows, displayobject

There's the problem. I need to display the fields of PJ1 to PJ8 but just the same row. Each row is a different account. So, how could I take the content of the fields and display them like this:

- Account one: PJ1
- Account one: PJ2
- Account one: PJ3...

and NOT like this:

- Account one: PJ1
- Account two: PJ1
- Account three: PJ1...

Here's the structure of the table.

[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: Where is the account number in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through each field in the row/record, rather than just iterating through each row in the result.

So you have something along the lines of:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query_result)) {
    echo $row[0];
}
```

But what you really want is:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query_result)) {
    foreach ($row as $field) {
        echo $field;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION`

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT account_num, PJ1
    FROM table
    UNION
    SELECT account_num, PJ2
    FROM table
    UNION
    SELECT account_num, PJ3
    FROM table
    ...
)
ORDER BY account_num
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$query="SELECT * FROM table ";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$i=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
{
 echo "account no :-"."$i"."$row['pj1']"."</br>";//you can add more column
 $i++;
}
```

Comment: This will only return the first column.